# Powershell New-AzKustoCluster Assigning existing VNET-Subnet doesn't let creating the cluster

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-explorer

Trying to assign a pre-created VNET-Subnet's Resource Id to the VirtualNetworkConfigurationSubnetId
property of the "New-AzKustoCluster" powershell module and it doesn't let me create the Azure Data Explorer cluster at all.

If I remove the Subnet setting, the cluster is created fine. I need to create the cluster into a VNET, so this setting is a MUST.

Code being used -

```
$location = "Central India"
$sku = "Dev(No SLA)_Standard_E2a_v4"

$virtualNetworks = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name $vnetName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
$subnetDetails = Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $subnetName -VirtualNetwork $virtualNetworks
$subnetId = $subnetDetails.Id

New-AzKustoCluster -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $clusterName -Location $location - 
SkuName $sku -SkuTier Basic -EnableDiskEncryption -IdentityType 'SystemAssigned' -SkuCapacity 1 
-VirtualNetworkConfigurationSubnetId $subnetId
```

Please suggest, what I may be doing wrong. Any help / suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing the rest of the parameters needed to configure your cluster on vent, specifically enginePublicIpId, and dataManagementPublicIpId:

```
      "subnetId": "[variables('subnetId')]",
      "enginePublicIpId": "[variables('enginePublicIpId')]",
      "dataManagementPublicIpId": "[variables('dataManagementPublicIpId')]"
```

Please read more on the steps to create a cluster with vent [here] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/vnet-create-cluster-portal) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/vnet-deployment). You can also deploy your cluster on vent using the following [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-kusto-vnet/azuredeploy.json)

Comment: I did add those 2 properties initially by first creating 2 Public IPs using New-AzPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $location -IdleTimeoutInMinutes 10 -AllocationMethod Static -Name lpublicip -Tier Regional -Sku Standard -IpAddressVersion IPv4 -Force and $publicIngestionIp = New-AzPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $location -IdleTimeoutInMinutes 10 -AllocationMethod Static -Name lpublicingestionip -Tier Regional -Sku Standard -IpAddressVersion IPv4 -Force and then using them in the New-AzKustoCluster command. But in vain.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So finally I have got it fully working. 3 things that were missing outside of my powershell itself, which was causing the script to fail (apparently though, the New-AzKustoCluster module doesn't throw any error / warning, for what it fails, so difficult to tell, what should be corrected).
But here it is. The changes that had to be done

1. Defining NSG and RouteTable to the subnet that is created on the VNET is a MUST, as without this, the New-AzKustoCluster function fails, but doesn't throw any errors as such. It's only when we use these resources to create a cluster thru portal, is when it shows the deployment of cluster has failed due to this reason.
2. A NSG rule should be defined on the subnet (being used to deploy the cluster to) to allow the incoming traffic from AzureDataExplorerManagement and AzureLoadBalancer addresses (using these 2 Source service tags).
3. The route table is to defined on the subnet, and it should contain a route with AddressPrefix='/32' and NextHopType='Internet'

Once these 3 steps were completed, outside of the main powershell itself, then the script completed fine, without any issues and creating the cluster, db and table as required.

Hope this helps someone use the New-AzKustoCluster functionality in powershell without any roadblocks.